# Creating an employee class and emplyoee class demo?

Tags: java, class, methods

We have to use set and get methods to such as

- `Employee()`
- `Employee(empId:int)`
- `Employee(empId:int, payRate:double, weeklyHrs:double)`
- `setId(empId:int):void`
- `setPayRate(payRate:double):void`
- `setHrs(weeklyHrs:double):void`
- `getId():int`
- `getPayRate():double`
- `getHrs():double`
- `getWeeklyPay():double`
- `toString():String`

to create an employee class and employee class demo. We have to use two employee id's and type in their weekly hours and pay to return how much they made. Here is what I have down for the Employee class:

```
      //@param
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //Scanner object
    public void setID(int empID){
      System.out.println("Enter employee 1's id: ");
      String input2 = input.next();
      int emp1 = Integer.parseInt(input2);
      System.out.println("Enter employee 2's id: ");
      String input3 = input.next();
      int emp2 = Integer.parseInt(input3);     
    }
    //@param
    public void setPayRate(double payRate){
      System.out.println("Enter employee 1's payrate: ");
      String input4 = input.next();
      double pay1 = Double.parseDouble(input4);
      System.out.println("Enter employee 2's payrate: ");
      String input5 = input.next();
      double pay2 = Double.parseDouble(input5);  
    } 
    //@param
    public void setHrs(double weeklyHrs){
      System.out.println("Enter employee 1's hours: ");
      String input6 = input.next();
      double hour1 = Double.parseDouble(input6);
      System.out.println("Enter employee 2's hours: ");
      String input7 = input.next();
      double hour2 = Double.parseDouble(input7); 
    }

//GET METHODS
    public int getID(int empID){
      return empID;  
    }
    public double getHrs(double hours){
      return hours;
    }
    public double getWeeklyPay(double pay){
      return pay;
    }

//DISPLAY ANSWERS


    public String toString(int emp1,int emp2,double hour1,double hour2,double pay1,double pay2){

      String myString= String.format("The first employee's ID is: " + emp1 + 
                                     "The second employee's ID is: " + emp2 +
                                     "The first employee's hours are: " + hour1 +
                                     "The secondemployee's hours are: " + hour2 +
                                     "The first employee's pay: $%,.2f"+ pay1*hour1 +
                                     "The second employee's pay: $%,.2f" + pay2*hour2,
                                     emp1,emp2,hour1,hour2,pay1,pay2);
      return myString;

    }

  }//End of class
```

I'm just wondering what I would put in my Employee Class Demo so that it would be able to return the toString method?

Comment: I don't see any class defined in your code.

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println()` calls the `toString()` method automatically on any object you pass into it - alternatively, you can just call it yourself:

```
Employee e;

// properly initialize e

System.out.println(e); // works
System.out.println(e.toString()); // also works
```

As a side note, your `toString()` method is incorrect. It should be a member function of the `Employee` class - making it a method that *takes* `Employee` objects is the wrong way to do it (assuming you want to follow standard Java OOP practices).

The proper method would look something like this:

```
// Notice no arguments are passed in
public String toString() {

    // Instead, we use the "this" variable
    return String.format("My ID is %s, my hours are %f, and my pay is $%,.2f", this.empID, this.hours, this.pay);
}
```